# ignore specific line on csv file based on the fixed character

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I have very big csv files which contain transaction log of the bank. Valid transaction id are enclosed by <>. The format is like below

```
012,10/1/2013,<13273288163624>JOHN doe .,<01-10-2013>20130930,13273288163624,10/1/2013,"10,580.00",
012,10/1/2013,SI TRANSFER,10/1/2013,"11,330,114.07",
012,10/1/2013,<555395056216>JOHN DOE1,<01-10-2013>,555395056216,10/1/2013,"46,852.00",
012,10/1/2013,<13273708949197>JOHN DOE3 -,<01-10-2013>20130930,13273708949197,10/1/2013,"57,687.00",
```

The advantage we have is that the line which does not contain '<' and '>'   need to be ignored.

Is there any way to ignore those lines of csv to have csv files contents like below?

```
012,10/1/2013,<13273288163624>JOHN doe .,<01-10-2013>20130930,13273288163624,10/1/2013,"10,580.00",
012,10/1/2013,<555395056216>JOHN DOE1,<01-10-2013>,555395056216,10/1/2013,"46,852.00",
012,10/1/2013,<13273708949197>JOHN DOE3 -,<01-10-2013>20130930,13273708949197,10/1/2013,"57,687.00",
```

I want to use csv in mssql bulk insert like below

```
BULK
INSERT nibl
FROM 'd:\2.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRSTROW=2
)
GO
```

Invalid transaction (the line without < and >) have fewer no of columns , which result in failure of bulk insert

i dont want to use loops using fgetcsv beacuse csv size is even greater than 100 mb

Comment: why are you manually splitting/parsing csv? use `fgetcsv()` and then `if (substr($row[2], 0, 1) == '<')) { continue; }`.

Comment: Agree with Marc B. I use [**splfileobject**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) and `->seek()` / `->fgetcsv()` when I need to parse huge CSV-files (200-400mb) - take a look at that.

Comment: i am trying to do bulk insert without using fgetcsv . it will really slow down the entire process.. no loop please\

Comment: then you can't import the file using this method. the csv's format has to be constant for every row. if you don't want to loop/insert from php, at least loop/filter in php, and generate a .csv which CAN be directly loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no loop just use explode,array_filter  and implode

```
<?php
$csv=file_get_contents("1.csv");
$arr=explode("\n",$str);
function filter($str){
    return strpos($str,"<");
}
$new_arr=array_filter($arr,"filter");
$str=implode("\n",$new_arr);
file_put_contents("1.csv",$str);
?>
```